# this.image.width / number yields 0

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the width of a sprite using the image width, but the number always comes out as 0, why is that?

```
function SpriteSheet(image, numFramesX, numFramesY, totalFrames) {
    this.image = image;
    this.numFramesX = numFramesX;
    this.numFramesY = numFramesY;
    this.totalFrames = totalFrames;

    this.spriteWidth = this.image.width / this.numFramesX;
    this.spriteHeight = this.image.height / this.numFramesY;
}

image.onload = function() {
console.log('Image has been loaded');
}
image.src = 'dance.png';
spritesheet = new SpriteSheet(image, 8, 10, 80);
```

spritesheet.spriteWidth and spritesheet.spriteHeight always yields 0.  I cornered the problem to 'this.image.width' since it works if I put in the width of the image manually.

```
this.spriteWidth = 880 / this.numFramesX;
```

instead of

```
this.spriteWidth = this.image.width / this.numFramesX;
```

It also works if I calculate it using the object in the console:

```
spritesheet.image.width / spritesheet.numFramesX
```

yields 110

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunwooz/kxrEH/1)

Comment: what does alert(this.image.width) and alert(this.numFramesX) show you?

Comment: I wrote it in the console and I get 880 and 'undefined' respectively.  How does the console know that I'm referring to the spritesheet object(using 'this')?

Comment: That can't be right, because the code works if I just replace 'this.image.width' with just a number '880'. Leaving this.numFramesX

Comment: Because this.numFramesX should be resolved to a value before that value is passed to the console. Can you make sure you're pasting your actual code, and not retyping some of it.

Comment: I posted it on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sunwooz/kxrEH/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that?

```
window.onload = function () {
    console.log('Image has been loaded');
    image.src = 'dance.png';
    spritesheet = new SpriteSheet(image, 8, 10, 80);
}
```

Comment: spritesheet object is undefined. console.log never gets called.  I also tried doing image.onload = (your code)

Comment: ahh it worked, i was being an idiot.  I was reassigning image every loop. Thanks a lot!